# how can I make .gitignore work?

Tags: git, grails, ggts

I'm using grails, ggts and generated my `.gitignore` file by 
    integrate-with  --git

it contains a line

```
/target/
```

which I think should exclude target contents especially the generated war-file from versioning.
But all target contents is included in repository update.

How to avoid that?

Answer (score 1):

It target was already versioned, adding a .gitignore with /target/ in it won't change that.

You would need to remove that folder from the index first, and record that deletion, before the .gitignore applies.

```
git rm -r --cached target/
git commit -m "remove target from index"
```